# Cucumber not finding @Findby annotations

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java, page-objects, cucumber

Im trying to set up cucumber over my page object.
I currently have as my login page object:

```
@FindBy (id  = cF.username)           public WebElement username;
@FindBy (id  = cF.password)           public WebElement password;
@FindBy (id  = cF.loginButton)        public WebElement loginButton;


@Test
public websiteProspector_beta doLogin(String myUsername, String myPassword) throws IOException {
    logs.InfoDetails("Logging Into Tomcat8- 2092");

    try {
        username.sendKeys(myUsername);
        password.sendKeys(myPassword);
        loginButton.click();
        {...}
```

and my step description as:

```
    @And("^I log into ao$")
public void i_log_into_ao() throws Throwable {
    actonLogin = new actonLogin(driver);
    actonLogin.doLogin(cF.loginUsername, cF.loginPassword);
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

When i run it, it successfully runs the first two steps, however when it comes to an object with @findby, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.acton.PageObjects.loginPage.actonLogin.doLogin(actonLogin.java:41)
at com.acton.cucumber.cucumberSteps.i_log_into_ao(cucumberSteps.java:41)
at ✽.And I log into ao(com/acton/cucumber/login.feature:6)
```

The reason why I know it's due to the @Findby is because when I change the login page object to use "driver.findelement(By...." it's successful with no errors.
is there something im missing?

I am new to cucumber and automation all together, any help i can get is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Did you run `PageFactory.initElements`? The PageFactory magic won't actually parse the annotations until you do so. I usually put into the constructor a line like:

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```

So that it runs when I construct the page.