# how to Iterate a List of links?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath, page-objects, css

This "Books" [link](http://books.toscrape.com/) shows that it has the following `xpath`:

```
/html/body/div/div/div/aside/div[2]/ul/li/a
```

Then follows the catalogue categories:  Travel, Mystery, etc.  Reading the `xpath` above I see three consecutive `div`, an `aside`, then another `div` before we start to get to the list.

Within that last division there seems some *a priori* knowledge is required that "Books" is the title for the list and not a list item itself.

To get the categories, I would want the list items?  Currently, [I'm getting all the links](https://github.com/THUFIR/com.toscrape.books.selenium) for the `PageObjectModel` as [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/36996/8900).

1.)  How can I get just the list items and the link for that item?

2.)  How reasonable is my approach towards scraping data from this sample site?

code:

```
package dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

class WelcomePage {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());
    private WebDriver webDriver = null;

    @FindBy(partialLinkText = "Books")
    private WebElement books;

    @FindBy(tagName = "a")
    List<WebElement> links;

    private WelcomePage() {
    }

    WelcomePage(WebDriver webDriver) {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;
        PageFactory.initElements(this.webDriver, this);
        LOG.info(webDriver.getCurrentUrl());
    }

    static WelcomePage init(WebDriver webDriver) {
        return new WelcomePage(webDriver);
    }

    void populateCatalogue() {
        LOG.fine("start..");
        for (WebElement webElement : links) {
            LOG.info(webElement.getText());
        }
        LOG.fine("..done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Books" is a single list item, which contains a new list with the categories. So you need to go deeper into that list like this:

```
//div[@class='side_categories']/ul/li/ul/li/a
```

In test code, it should look like something this:

```java
@FindBy(xpath= "//div[@class='side_categories']/ul/li/ul/li/a")
List<WebElement> links;
```

Then to get the link and the item name:

```java
for (WebElement webElement : links) {
    LOG.info(webElement.getText());
    LOG.info(webElement.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Comment: how did you find the division name, side_categories?

Comment: @Thufir I have used the inspect element (Ctrl + Shift + C) functionality of my browser.

Comment: I know.  It's just a bunch jibberish to me.  I meant, how did you read the source code?  Just knowledge of html, css, javascript?

Comment: @Thufir Just HTML, if you inspect the "Books" element you can observe a div with class attribute of "side_categories", then you can copy the inner HTML to narrow down the source. There are many online xpath testers to experiment with.